# Use variable inside another variable in a mail blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using the Mail library in Laravel to send html email with custom data passed to a blade view.

The problem born when the mail has to render the html fetched from a row in the database which include a variable that i pass through the view.

This is my build function in my mailable class

```php
public function build()
{
   return $this->from('hello@test.it')
     ->view('view')
     ->with([
       'url'     => 'https://google.com',
       'text' => $this->parameters->text,
      ]);
}
```

Then in the blade view:

```php
<div>
  {!! $text !!}
</div>
```

This is what the $text variable looks like:

```html
<p>
  <span>This is my text for the mail</span>
  <a href="{{ $url }}">Click here to compile</a>
</p>
```

The link href shoul contain the url variable value instead of not passing the variable name itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be formating with php:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('hello@test.it')
     ->view('view')
     ->with([
       'text' => str_replace('{{ $url }}','https://google.com',$this->parameters->text)
      ]);
 }
```

Comment: This can't work because the $url variable passed inside the str_replace, will be interprted as variable not as string

Answer (score 0):

I did not try by myself but you could make an attempt with `Blade::compileString()`, i.e.:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('hello@test.it')
      ->view('view')
      ->with([
        'url'     => 'https://google.com',
        'text' => \Blade::compileString($this->parameters->text),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This looks great but it remove the variable without replacing with anything.

Comment: Please try with normal var expansion `<a href="$url"` and without Blade::compileString()

Comment: It simply transform the url in "$url"

This is what the code looks like now:
```lang-php
return $this->from('hello@test.it')
  ->view('view')
  ->with([
    'url'     => 'https://google.com',
    'text' => $this->parameters->text,
  ]);
```
In the db:
```lang-html
<p>
  <span>This is my text for the mail</span>
  <a href="$url">Click here to compile</a>
</p>
```